# Why is my code not working faster after I edited it?

Tags: python, python-2.5

I'm new to computer science and programming. I'm taking a free online class in coding, and one of the assignments was to write a program that will generate the 1000th prime number.

FYI, this is in Python 2.5.4

Here is the original code I copied (and edited a little bit) from another thread on this forum:

```
def isprime(n):

    if n<2:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(2,(n/2+1)):
            if n%i==0:
                return False
        else:
            return True

def nthprime(n):
    x=[]
    j=2
    while len(x)<n:
        if (isprime(j)) == True:
            x.append(j)
        j =j+1
    return(x[n-1])

print nthprime(1000)
```

However, I thought I could make the program faster by rewriting the isprime(n) function as follows:

```
def isprime(n):# First the primality test
    i=1
    if n<2:
        return False
    if (n!=2 and (n/2*2==n)):
        return False
    if n==3:
        return True
    if n==5:
        return True
    else:
        while i <= (n/2+1):
            i+=2
            if n%i==0:
                return False
        else:
              return True
```

That way, when it is only checking if n is divisible by odd integers (by this point in the code, we already know n is odd, and therefore not divisible by any even integers).

I thought that rewriting it this way would make the program work twice as fast (since it's only checking half as many numbers), but it seems to be taking the same amount of time, or even slightly longer, than what it was taking before.

Also, is there any way to rewrite the second block of code to get rid of the:

```
if n==3:
    return True
if n==5:
    return True
```

The only reason I included that is because I realized my algorithm was generating "false" for 3 and 5, even though they are prime.

Comment: Why are you learning a version of python that is nine years old? You should look at python `3.6`

Comment: `if n in [3,5]: return True` or `if n == 3 or n == 5: return True`

Comment: Hint: if you are looking for factor pairs, one factor will always be <= the square root of the product.

Comment: You should time your code.  Your new version is 42% faster, measured on my system.

Comment: `n/2*2==n` is a bad (and wrong in Python 3) way of checking for even numbers.

Comment: BTW, the reason 3 and 5 were `false` was because you do `i += 2` before checking to see if it was prime, so you ended up testing `3%3` and `5%5`. Retaining the structure of the old code, you could keep the `for` and step by two: `for i in range(3,(n/2+1), 2)`, or `for i in range(3,(math.sqrt(n)+1), 2)` for a better upper limit.

Comment: Thank you.

I'm learning a version that is 9 years old because I'm doing a free online course on ocw.mit.edu (MIT Open Courseware) that is from Fall 2008.

Comment: Mark Tolonen, what system do you use to time the speed of a program?

Answer (score 3):

I see what you were going for with your optimizations, but I think the logic you've implemented isn't what you were going for. Think instead about other ways you can reduce the number of numbers you have to check.

The first one I'd recommend is instantly ruling out even numbers:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n < 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    # ...
```

The other big spot you're checking way more than you need to is in the factor checking that you fall back on when the optimizations fail. You don't need to go all the way to `n / 2`; The largest factor you need to worry about is `sqrt(n)` (once you've passed root `n`, you start checking factors whose pair you've already checked, e.g. if you're checking `n = 6`, once you check 2, you've already checked 3). Here's the corresponding optimization:

```
def isprime(n):
    # ...
    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
```

All together, here's the new `isprime` (EDIT: with tips from comments):

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 2: return True
    if n % 2 == 0: return False

    for i in xrange(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0: return False

    return True
```

Calculating `nthprime(5000)`, these 2 optimizations took my time from **8.497** seconds to **0.108** seconds.

EDIT: [demo](https://repl.it/JEsc)

Comment: `int(n ** .5) + 1`, actually, when used with `range` (which should be `xrange` on Python 2.x).  At least check that the 1000th prime is 7919.

Comment: @treecoder I'm curious, what's wrong with `math.sqrt()`?

Comment: You're not taking as much advantage of ruling out even `n` values as much as you could. You can skip checking even factors too. I'd do `if n == 2: return True`, `if n % 2 == 0: return False`, `for i in xrange(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2): ...`.

Comment: @KenY-N math.sqrt(10000) took 286ns on my system.  10000**.5 took 23.6ns. (checked using `timeit` module).

Comment: Nothing wrong with `math.sqrt` per se, but when we can use an operator for something, using function does not feel idiomatic. Nothing wrong with `add(1,1)` -- but `1+1` feels better. Although you could say that `math.sqrt` is more readable for those not familiar with `**`.

Comment: And the profiling could go in favor of `**` also as Mark Tolonen points out.

Comment: Just curious, what is the difference between "range" and "xrange"? Is it just a difference between versions of Python? I'm on Python 2.5.4 and "range" works fine. "xrange" turns purple when I type it, but I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: `xrange` gives a range object instead of a list. This means that the generated numbers are only loaded into memory as needed (ie with each successive iteration) instead of all at once into the list. In Python 3, this became the default behavior of the `range` builtin (you can still achieve the old behavior with `list(range(n))`)